# Function to add struct to another struct in C

Tags: c

so I have 3 structs here:

```
typedef struct {
    char *name; // allocated
    int commonality;
    int weight;
} monster;

typedef struct {
    char *name; // allocated
    char *description; // allocated
    double area;
    int monsters;
    monster **monsters; // allocated
} region;
typedef struct {
    char *name; // allocated
    double diameter;
    int regions;
    region **regions; // allocated
} planet;
```

I already have function:

```
monster *new_monster(char *name, int commonality, int weight);
```

I am trying to create these functions:

```
void add_monster_to_region(region *r, char *mname, int mcommonality, int weight);
void delete_region_from_planet(planet *p, char *rname);
```

This is what I have so far, but I don't believe it's right, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

```
void add_monster_to_region(region *r, char *mname, int mcommonality, int mweight) 
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < mcommonality; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(mname, r->monsters[i]->name) == 0)
        {
            r->monsters[i]->name = mname;
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Not a good design. Prefer this: `add_monster_to _region(region* r, monster* m)`.

Comment: I second what @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. said, but I also wonder what you are even trying to do here. Shouldn't the for loop have `i < r->numMonsters`? (implicitly i've renamed the `int monsters;` variable because you can't have two `monsters` variables). Furthermore, you're looping through an array of monsters in the region checking each of their names, which is just begging for a segmentation fault since you cannot be sure that each monster in the array has been initialized.

Comment: If `r->monsters[i]->name` is "allocated" as per your comments, which I assume means allocated by the memory management functions, then `r->monsters[i]->name = mname;` seems to be leaking the memory pointed to by the previous value.

Comment: What do you mean by a monster's commonality? Why do you have two members of the monster struct named "monsters".

Comment: What does `monster **monsters; // fully allocated, NOT a reference array` mean?  Especially the 'fully allocated' part?  Since you have `new_monster()`, your `add_monster_to_region()` function _should_ take a `monster *`.  Failing that, you should be calling `new_monster()` in `add_monster_to_region()`.  If the names are equal, why are you copying the new name pointer over the old one?  Don't you need to free the old name?  You don 't show how the memory management for names is done. As it stands, you're likely to leak memory. If the monster name isn't found, shouldn't you add the new monster?

Answer (score 1):

It would be very helpful to have a minimal reproducible example. It would also clarify what was meant with *fully allocated NOT a reference array*.

Nevertheless, here is my take on how to create a planet, two regions and how to populate the regions with monsters:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char *name; // allocated
    int commonality;
    int weight;
} monster;

typedef struct {
    char *name; // allocated
    char *description; // allocated
    double area;
    int monster_count;
    monster **monsters; // fully allocated, NOT a reference array
} region;

typedef struct {
    char *name; // allocated
    double diameter;
    int region_count;
    region **regions; // fully allocated, NOT a reference array
} planet;

monster *new_monster(char *name, int commonality, int weight) {
    monster *new_monster = calloc(sizeof(monster), 0);
    if (new_monster != NULL) {
        new_monster->name = strdup(name);
        if (new_monster->name == NULL) {
            free(new_monster);
            return NULL;
        }
        new_monster->commonality = commonality;
        new_monster->weight = weight;
    }
    return new_monster;
}

void free_monster(monster *the_monster) {
    if (the_monster != NULL) {
        if (the_monster->name != NULL) {
            free(the_monster->name);
        }
        free(the_monster);
    }
}

void add_monster_to_region(region *r, char *mname, int mcommonality, int mweight) 
{
    monster *a_monster = new_monster(mname, mcommonality, mweight);
    if (a_monster == NULL) return; // no memory

    monster **monsters = NULL;

    if (r->monsters != NULL) {
        monsters = realloc(r->monsters, (r->monster_count + 1) * sizeof(monster *));
    } else {
        monsters = calloc(sizeof(monster *), 0);
    }

    if (monsters == NULL) {
        free_monster(a_monster);
        return; // no memory
    }

    r->monsters = monsters;
    r->monsters[r->monster_count] = a_monster; 
    r->monster_count++;
}

void delete_region_from_planet(planet *p, char *rname) {
    // TODO
}

int main() {
    region desert = {"Desert", "Sunny and warm place.", 50.0, 0, NULL};
    region ocean = {"Ocean", "Huge wet place.", 500.0, 0, NULL};
    region *regions[] = {&desert, &ocean};
    planet mud = {"Mud", 100.00, 2, regions};

    add_monster_to_region(&desert, "Bug", 100, 100);
    add_monster_to_region(&desert, "Zombie", 10, 20);
    add_monster_to_region(&ocean, "Shark", 20, 40);

    for (int i = 0; i < mud.region_count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mud.regions[i]->monster_count; j++) {
            printf("%s %d %d\n",
                mud.regions[i]->monsters[j]->name,
                mud.regions[i]->monsters[j]->commonality,
                mud.regions[i]->monsters[j]->weight
            );
        }
    }

    // TODO: release allocated memory

    return 0;
}
```

We can see all monsters in all regions of the defined planet:

```
$ gcc -Wall monsters.c
$ ./a.out             
Bug 100 100
Zombie 10 20
Shark 20 40
$
```

Comment: Mostly good, but when you free a monster in the error case in `add_monster_to_region()`, you leak the memory allocated by `strdup()` in `new_monster()`.  You should probably have a `free_monster()` function or thereabouts that frees a monster allocated by `new_monster()`, and that is used to release the allocated monster fully.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the hint. I implemented it.